# How the MediaWiki shows template infobox field with two name?

Tags: mediawiki

I have infobox templte like:

```
{{Infobox
  |image         = {{{image|}}}
}}
```

and i want that template show image even if user type **blablabla** instead of **image**.what should i do ?

Comment: You mean he did type `|blablabla=imagepath`? You cannot catch-them-all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have “aliases“ for parameter names like this: `{{{image|{{{picture|{{{file|}}}}}}}}}`. This will work for `image = ...`, `picture = ...`, and `file = ...`.

It's not possible to get the value of *any* parameter name, though.

Comment: Thank a lot , it was bothering me for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If the user mistypes the parameter name, you cannot catch that [in the template alone][with standard template functions].

If you want the user to freely choose a parameter name, you can do that but he needs to tell you the parameter name. Example:

```
The {{{1}}} is {{{{{{1}}}}}}.
```

```
{{MyTemplate|parameter|parameter=variably named}}
->
The parameter is variably named.
```